# How to pass collection items to a bean through XML JSP?

Tags: jsp, jspx

Given a Java bean class with a collection property is there any way to pass collection items to that property using XML JSP?

For instance, the following code:

```
<jsp:useBean id="myBean"
        class="com.corp.project.MyBean" scope="page">
    <jsp:setProperty name="myBean" 
        property="items" value="first value" />
    <jsp:setProperty name="myBean" 
        property="items" value="second value" />
</jsp:useBean>
```

MyBean has an Items collection property. Is there a way to pass multiple values to be added to that collection?

Comment: Why don't you do that in your controller, using Java code? Nobody should use jsp:useBean and jsp:setProperty anymore.

Comment: That's good to know. I am using Adobe AEM and I am not sure how to access the controller. Either way my question is about XML JSP not beans.  Another example would be passing items to a taglib.